# How to display the Project Version as Release name in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the release version in `pom.xml`. For Example, **xyz-0.0.1** is the version in my `pom.xml`. Azure Build creating the package.

I want to use the version **xyz-0.0.1** as a release name in the release pipeline. How can I pass the version to release pipeline and set "Release name format" in options?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the version is in a file (pom.xml) you can't put the version in the "Release name format", you need during the release to extract the version from the file and assign the release number.

You can do it with a PowerShell script (I write the concept, you need to find out how exactly to get the xml node):

```
$file = Get-Content th/to/pom.xml
# Read the version with something like this:
# $version = Select-Xml -Content $file -XPath "//version"
# Then update the Release name:
Write-Host "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$version"
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. You cannot change the release name after the process has begun. It expects the release name to be retrievable at release start time. You can use variable groups to share variables between build and release pipelines, because they have already been set and are available at release start. Info: you always have to combine your variable (in this case your version number) with an automatic one, like release number/id. A fixed one is not allowed because it could happen that your release numbers will not be unique.

Comment: @SteveRakebrandt This is works for me. you can update the release name after the release started, did you try it?

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. But the release name has to be always unique.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can use here a maven help plugin.

I'm doing it this way (using bash step):

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**[your project dir]**/
v=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$v"
```

And yes, release version should be unique. To change it inside the script, I use:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=[x.y.z]-RELEASE
```

or you can use release plugin:

```
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=[x.y.z]-RELEASE
```